# Removing Console window in Nim

Tags: console, nim-lang

I have written a program in Nim, which on execution opens a blank cmd

I found that using switches during compilation this can be removed, But I don't want to use any contemplation flags.
Means as in C language, we use

```
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(console, SW_HIDE);
```

to hide the window
So, is there any code that I can write inside my Nim Program that will hide the gui console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the compiler user guide, it has an 'app' flag, if you're making a GUI app, passing `--app:gui` should work for your app, hope this helps!

(Slight edit as I misread the question) You can put this into a `config.nims` file in the same folder as the main file, to pass flags to the compiler without doing it via the command line.

https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#compiler-usage-commandminusline-switches